# Unity UIButton onClick in Cardboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclick, uibutton, google-cardboard

I have a problem with the `UIButton` in Unity. I am following this example [here](https://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/cardboard-unity#4).

But the `UIButton` isn't recognized when I'm in Cardboard mode. Everything is working perfectly fine if I run in preview instead of deploying it to my Android phone. When I run in my phone, no matter how many times I try or how I press the button, it does not start the game or change the cardboard mode.

I verified that when I press the screen/press the Cardboard trigger button, the trigger button is actually fired. I verified this by printing a debug statement in the `Update()` method `if Cardboard.SDK.Triggerred`.

Can anyone explain what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem comes in the GazeInputModule.cs script file. The GameObject that the gaze is pointing is actually pointing at the Text object instead of the button itself. Hence no onClick function is fired.

To fix this, I simply reassign the gameobject to the button instead of the text.